# please can anyone help me to convert this regular expression pattern from javascript to c#

Tags: javascript, regex, c#-4.0

please can anyone help me to convert this regular expression pattern from javascript to c#

```
 var phonePattern = /^(([^\.\-\,a-wy-z]([\(]?(\+|[x])?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?([\(]?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?(\d+[\s\.\-\,]?)+[^\.\-\,a-z])|((\+|[x])?\d+))$/i
```

i need to validate phone number i'll take the value from textbox and i'll compare it with regex pattern i need to convert this pattern specifically because This pattern will address almost most of the country phone patterns like UK, US, eurpoe, india etc.

this is my c# code

```
Regex REphone = new Regex(@" c# pattern here");
if (REphone.IsMatch(TextBox_Phone.Text)) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried for the .NET regex so far? And in what way isn't it working?

Comment: Regex REphone =   new Regex(@"^(([^\.\-\,a-wy-z]([\(]?(\+|[x])?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?([\(]?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?(\d+[\s\.\-\,]?)+[^\.\-\,a-z])|((\+|[x])?\d+))$",
i try this but didn't work always go on else even i entered right values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Regex(@"^(([^\.\-\,a-wy-z]([\(]?(\+|[x])?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?([\(]?\d+[\)]?)?[\s\.\-\,]?(\d+[\s\.\-\,]?)+[^\.\-\,a-z])|((\+|[x])?\d+))$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The pattern itself is the same, but quoted between `@"`, `"` instead of `/`, `/`.

`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` makes the match case-insensitive, which is the equivalent to the `i` flag on the end of your JavaScript regex literal.

Comment: @fatma mansour: If Daniel's answer addressed your question satisfactorily, you really should consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript delimits regex using `/` and C# doesn't use delimiters (you pass it in as a string so technically you could say it is delimited by double-quotes `"`).

Also, in C# strings remember you have to escape backslashes from `\` to `\\`.

So your regex expression would look like this -

```
"^(([^\\.\\-\\,a-wy-z]([\\(]?(\\+|[x])?\\d+[\\)]?)?[\\s\\.\\-\\,]?([\\(]?\\d+[\\)]?)?[\\s\\.\\-\\,]?(\\d+[\\s\\.\\-\\,]?)+[^\\.\\-\\,a-z])|((\\+|[x])?\\d+))$"
```

If you are going to pass it in as a string literal (by using the `@` in front of it) then you don't need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: I tried the @ and the \\ it doesn't work with me is this syntax valid in c#?